# Making a "CLI-like" progress bar in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, command-line-interface, progress-bar

So I'm working on a command line interface in the web. Currently, there is the start of a progress bar on the left of the CLI, and a few commands that work. I want to add more commands, but I felt that they needed to have a time delay feature to make it feel more authentic.

I want to make a function that, when called, will divide the (ms) used in the scenario by 12 (the number of dashes in the progress bar) and display an update every (ms).

The Progress bar looks something like this: **[------------]**

https://codepen.io/ZacV/pen/abEYpLz

```
function statsBar(ms){
  var timeChunk = Math.round(ms/12)
  for (let i = 0; i < timeChunk; i++) {
    document.getElementById("DispStatus").innerHTML = "[" + ("|" * timeChunk) + ("-" * (12 - timeChunk)) + "]"
    sleep(timeChunk);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get why people are disliking this post. I just need help on a progress bar.

Comment: You're supposed to post code that you think should work but doesn't and then people explain what you're missing. SO is not a free coding service. I think you're getting down votes because you're asking us to do it for you not asking for help figuring out why your approach isn't working.

Comment: I see. I apologize for the lack of upfront code. I was working on a snippit earlier, but i felt that it was no where near the answer. I will update with what i have so far now. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: No worries. Even just adding the `innerHTML = ` line helped a lot in narrowing down where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to schedule updates to the progress bar all at once but have them happen over time.

```js
function statsBar(ms){
  var timeChunk = Math.round(ms/12);
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("DispStatus").innerHTML = "[" + ('-'.repeat(i)) + "]";
    }, i * timeChunk);
  }
}
statsBar(6000);
```

```html
<div id="DispStatus"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! This works very Well! Im going to work on adding filler for the progress bar now and will post it as an answer after. Thank you so much for all your help! (Also thank you for the help with formatting my question)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After a bit of trial and error, I found the most efficient way to finish Rocky Sims snippet. Rocky Sims' code created a really nice and efficient progress bar, however the size of the bar was inconsistent. This final product includes a progress bar with a consistent width to match with the width of the div. Thanks for all of your guys' help on this!

```
function statsBar(ms){
  var timeChunk = Math.round(ms/12);
  for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("DispStatus").innerHTML = "[" + ('|'.repeat(i)) + ('-'.repeat(12 - i)) + "]";
    }, i * timeChunk);
  }
}
statsBar(6000);

<div id="DispStatus"></div>
```